# Downloading Governance Registry artifact in a archive file

Tags: wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

Is it possible to upload artifacts in a specific folder structure like :
/common/schemas/sample/ 
For instance allow an xsd that is uploaded to conform to a specific location for when it is downloaded and used in a different project it can follow the same folder naming and location standard.
For instance I want sample.xsd to be available under:
common/schemas/sample/sample.xsd
I want this xsd to be downloaded in this structure by default without having to create this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using WSO2 Governance Registry 5.x release. There you can change the artifact storage patch using the RXT configuration. More information can be found via "[Customizing the Storage Path for Configurable Governance Artifacts](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Customizing+the+Storage+Path+for+Configurable+Governance+Artifacts)"  doc.

Comment: Sure. I am using wso2greg-5.3.0. I see that the storage location is configurable from the admin console. the problem i am having is when i download this as a zip it is stored in a flat structure and does not contain the folders as it was stored.